# Android Json Parsing from fql query result

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-fql

I am developing a Facebook app for android.I am working with Facebook Stream  table.
It gives me correct output. But I uable to parse return json string.
 This is my Code :

```
void Query()
{
    try
    {
        String fql = "SELECT  attachment FROM   stream WHERE  post_id = '100008169074385_1408625132753109' ";

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

        parameters.putString("query", fql);
        parameters.putString("method", "fql.query");

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        // Log.v("esty", session.getAccessToken());

        if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()) {
            Log.v("esty", session.getAccessToken());
            Log.v("esty", session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString());
        }
        parameters.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());

        String response = null;    //hold my json String

        response = fb.request(parameters);  //Output JSON
        Log.v("esty2", response);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        Log.v("esty2", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

output josn is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "media": [
          {
            "href": "", 
            "alt": "", 
            "type": "swf", 
            "src": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=87741124305&v=1&size=p&cksum=993c530ba81d9bc6b98190f1f4bbcb08&src=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FOVOngbevN2o%2Fhqdefault.jpg", 
            "swf": {
              "source_url": "http://www.youtube.com/v/OVOngbevN2o?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDiJSXfsJTASx9eMq_HlenQ&version=3&feature=share&autohide=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=1", 
              "preview_img": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=87741124305&v=1&size=p&cksum=993c530ba81d9bc6b98190f1f4bbcb08&src=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FOVOngbevN2o%2Fhqdefault.jpg", 
              "width": 0, 
              "height": 0, 
              "expanded_width": 0, 
              "expanded_height": 0
            }
          }
        ], 
        "name": "AJAX Tutorial - 19 - Creating Themes with CSS (+playlist)", 
        "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVOngbevN2o&feature=share&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDiJSXfsJTASx9eMq_HlenQ&index=18", 
        "caption": "Playlist by thenewboston", 
        "description": "Visit my website at http://thenewboston.com for all of my videos! \r\n\r\nMy Google+ - https://plus.google.com/108291790892450338168/posts\r\nFacebook - http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheNewBoston/464114846956315\r\nMy Twitter - http://twitter.com/#!/bucky_roberts\r\nMy Other YouTube Channel - http://www.youtube.com/thenewbostontv\r\nDonate - https://www.paypal.co...", 
        "properties": [
        ], 
        "icon": "https://fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t39.2081-0/10173489_10152389525269306_987289533_n.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want source_url,preview_img from this json.

How can i parse this json. Please anyone help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

`JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);`

That will be your whole `JSON`.  Then you need to dig in to get the rest of it.

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject firstElement = data.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray media = firstElement.getJSONObject("attachment").getJSONArray("media");
JSONObject anotherFirstElement = media.getJSONObject(0);
String source_url = anotherFirstElement.getJSONObject("sfw").getString("source_url");
```

To dig in and see what is going on, you can always do a `System.out.println(json.toString(4));` to see what is going on in each element.

Comment: its gives an exception: jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

Comment: Didn't notice media was nested inside attachments at first glance.  Try it now, @this.esty